# X11 Programming: Get notified if new window appeared?

Tags: c, x11

programming in C with the X11 library, is there a way to get notified if a new window  has appeared? I found [XSetAfterFunction](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/XSetAfterFunction.html) but its intended for debugging purposes only ...

Thanks for your help!

Heinrich

@edit:

This code solves my problem

```
int main() {    
Display* display = XOpenDisplay(":2");

XSetWindowAttributes attributes;
attributes.event_mask = SubstructureNotifyMask | StructureNotifyMask;

XChangeWindowAttributes(display, 0x100, CWEventMask, &attributes);

while (true) {
    XEvent event;
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
    std::cout << "Event occured" << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a window manager? Which one?

Comment: I am not using a window manager. Just Xvfb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory, you can use XChangeWindowAttributes to listen to events from the root window, then act on XMapEvent (or XCreateWindowEvent or whateverEvent depending on your definition of "a new window has appeared").

Comment: I posted my code above in my thread, it is not really working. I also tried it with XSelectInput().